# Java + Web interface

Tags: java

I'm writing a small application and I want to visualize results so I can see them in a web browser. For example, I want to display a plot of my data points.

Sure, I can write a http listener, that will serve an programatically built html. Or I can use java web application stack, but this seems a bit heavy weight for this simple task.

What do you recommend to do?

Comment: Dear OP, thanks for the wonderful letter I received, I would recommend contacting our SO hotline, at 1-555-5555. LMAO.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using an embedded Jetty Server in your application. It's small and lightweight, and doesn't require to write the http-listener.

[Embedding Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty)

The embedded jetty makes it easy to write a simple servlet and add some custom libraries.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Jetty server with a JSP page maybe? If you need to programmatically draw a plot from data points then you'll probably need extra libraries for that.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a HTML file containing the plot of your data points as an image? You would only need to install a small and lightwight http server?

If you want to create the plot on demand (when you display the website) and give it some parameters via URL I think you will need a Java Application Server (e.g. Glassfish, Tomcat, etc) and create a web-app that reads those parameters, computes your chart/image/whatever and then displays it in a jsp page